# Is it possible to create an App Widget from within an App in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-widget

Is it at all possible to create an App Widget programmatically from within an Android app itself? I'm rather lost on how to do this and Googling so far has led me to believe that it is not possible (that an App Widget and an App itself has to be separate applications).

So, would it be possible to dynamically create an App Widget from within an Android App? If not possible, how would you approach it? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it at all possible to create an App Widget programmatically from within an Android app itself?

That would depend completely upon what you mean by this.

> I'm rather lost on how to do this and Googling so far has led me to believe that it is not possible (that an App Widget and an App itself has to be separate applications).

No, an app widget most certainly can go in the same Android project as the rest of the application. In fact, usually it does.

> So, would it be possible to dynamically create an App Widget from within an Android App?

Again, you seem to think that the world knows what you mean by "dynamically", forcing us to guess.

An app widget, from the standpoint of code, consists of an `AppWidgetProvider`, an entry in the manifest pointing to that `AppWidgetProvider`, a metadata XML file, and whatever other resources you need (layouts, drawables, etc). All of that has to be written by a programmer and included in the app at compile time -- you cannot "dynamically" create those things.

An instance of an app widget is put on the home screen by the user, not by the programmer. Hence, a programmer cannot "dynamically" create instances of an app widget.

What the programmer *can* do "dynamically" is decide what is displayed inside of the app widget (e.g., current headlines for a news ticker, current song being played for a music player).

Comment: Sorry! I come from PHP land where almost everything can be dynamically generated. This is my second Android app - and the first to utilize widgets. So basically, I can add another <application></application> in the manifest and that would be the widget? Can the user activate the widget from within the application (IE, can the user take a picture within the app and then place the widget on the home screen?) How would one go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: @jsanc623: "So basically, I can add another <application></application> in the manifest and that would be the widget?" -- no, and you don't need to. As I wrote, an app widget most certainly can go in the same Android project as the rest of the application. An app widget can live alongside your app's activities, services, etc. in one `<application`>. "Can the user activate the widget from within the application" -- no, they would add the app widget from their home screen.